# how can change other selected element style using jquery

Tags: jquery, colors, border, siblings

I have 5 image in my html body and when user click on one of them jquery change style of clicked image and style of unclicked image

for example user click on image by img_choose1, the img_choose1 border will change to blue but the problem is here that other image border don't become to red
how can do that?

```
for (var i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
    $(body).append('<img  id="img_choose'+i+'" height="100" src="a'+i+'.jpg"/>');
}

$("[id^='img_choose']").click(function() {
    $(this).css("border","rgba(70,70,180,0.5) medium solid");

    //$(this).siblings().css("border","rgba(160,20,70,0.5) medium solid");
    // It don't change other selected elements border color
})
```

Comment: Please, post your completed code(HTML, CSS and etc) or provide a demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/305/)**

```
for (i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
    $('body').append('<img id="img_choose'+i+'" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">');
}

$('img').click(function() {
  $(this).css('border', '1px solid blue');
  $(this).siblings().css('border', '1px solid red');
});
```